# SwiftUI - What is ZStack and what is its difference with VStack?

Tags: ios, swiftui, vstack, hstack

I'm new to SwiftUI, sometimes instructor uses **VStack** and sometimes **ZStack** not able to understand the difference ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VStack`: Stacks the views in them vertically.

`ZStack`: Stacks the views in them over each other.